# Gracenote Mobile Client: Possibility to get the match probability?

Tags: android, gracenote

I would like to know whether there exists a possibility to get the match probability in percentage (or other measure factors) of a `GNSearchRespsonse`. The problem is that `getBestResponse()` doesn't return always the correct result so I would like to take only a match with high probability into account and refuse the others.

I searched a lot in the documentation. Although I didn't find any useful support.
Firstly I assumed that `boolean partial()` on an `GNSearchResponse` could returns me whether the match is sure or not but it's seems not to be this functionality. So what does this method do in general?

(I am using the Android SDK)

Comment: One dirty solution would be to track the music multiple times in series and only consider the result as correct if it is the same. However this needs more time to get a trustful result.

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing. Right now, the SDK return a result on nearly any audio, most being correct, but some not. It would be nice to filter out the incorrect ones.

Comment: I have not found any solution for this problem yet except the approach I have already mentioned

Comment: I posted a question about it here https://developer.gracenote.com/threshold-fingerprint-lookups